# Objective c - play mp3 stream frame by frame from memory buffer

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio, apple-tv

I would like to play mp3 audio stream by submitting audio frames one by one. 
I must submit it from memory buffer - without using mp3 file url (let's say that the mp3 streamed from the network and arrived in memory buffers).

Where from should I start? 
Is there any sample code that does this kind of thing?

Comment: Can you formulate it as an MP3 file? As in, could you arrange the bytes like that? I'm not asking that you write it to anywhere or at any point have the whole thing available but could I, as a consumer, keep asking you for the next byte and end up receiving a stream that looked like a valid MP3 file?

Comment: I'm not I fully understand your comment so please let me know if I didn't answer your question.  I'm getting the data in memory buffers (arrays of uint) frame by frame. The original data is coming from a real mp3 file so basically I can save all the buffers and play it but I want to play the data as soon as I can.. So technically, I think the answer to your question is Yes :)

Comment: I'm trying to decide whether it's worth advocating that you just write an `NSURLProtocol` subclass, giving you a way to act asynchronously as a data source for anybody that reads from a URL. I have to admit to being unsure what the latest is on sandboxing though (for DRM reasons, AVFoundation doesn't necessarily respect your `NSURLProtocol`s), so that may not be an answer. Have it as a throwaway comment unless or until I can update myself.

Comment: Thanks. I Eventually found the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be much simpler than i thought...

I just created:

```
    AVAudioPlayer* oAudioPlayer;
```

and the initialised it with data:

```
    oAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:chunk fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&error];
```

while chunk is some mp3 frames arrived from the network.

and eventually the playing method:

```
    if ([oAudioPlayer play] == false)
        NSLog(@"failed to play audio buffer");
```

If one wants to have a callback when frame has been finished to be played he can add a delegate before playing:

```
    oAudioPlayer.delegate = oSound;
```

while oSound is a class:

```
    @interface    SoundClass : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {}

    @property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

    - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
    - (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError * __nullable)error;

    @end
```

It seems that the audio player needs big buffers (i needed at least two frames in a raw to hear the sound).

Currently, the audio doesn't sound good enough but i guess it is something with the data feeding i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post a full piece of code for more clarity. Thanks!